# Electronic states of VO vanadium oxide in $C_{2v}$ point group

Tags: quantum-chemistry, transition-metals, group-theory

The electron configuration of $V^{2+}$: ... 3$d^{3}$ with 3 d electrons in 3 d orbitals. In $C_{\infty v}$, $d_{xz}$ and $d_{yz}$ have $\Pi$ IRREP; $d_{z}^{2}$ has $\Sigma^{+}$ IRREP; $d_{x^{2}-y^{2}}$ and $d_{xy}$ have $\Delta$ IRREP. So I think the 3 lowest lying  orbitals are $\Sigma^{+}$ and $\Pi$. The 2 possible spins are doublet and quartet. The 3 spatial occupations are

1. $\Sigma^{+}$ x $\Pi$  x $\Pi$ = $\Sigma^{+}$ + [$\Sigma^{-}$] + $\Delta$
2. $\Sigma^{+}$ x  $\Sigma^{+}$ x $\Pi$ = $\Pi$
3. $\Pi$ x $\Pi$ x $\Pi$ = ($\Sigma^{+}$ + [$\Sigma^{-}$] + $\Delta$) x $\Pi$ = $\Pi$ + $\Pi$ + $\Pi$ + $\Phi$

I only know that  $\Sigma^{+}$ is symmetric and $\Sigma^{-}$ is antisymmetric. But I'm not sure about other IRREPs' symmetry ($\Pi$, $\Delta$, $\Phi$). Also I don't know how the sum of many IRREPs which should also takes into account the various occupation permutations is transformed into $C_{2v}$. And since the $O^{2-}$ is fully occupied, only $V^{2+}$ contributes to the MOs. (Or is the concept of MO invalid in ionic bonding?) Is that correct?

Also a book recommendation for group theory in transition metal complex would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you know you’re looking at C2v symmetry, why do you look up the $C_{\infty v}$ irreps? You can find how the d orbitals transform in the C2v character table.

Comment: I think you should try to figure out the electronic states of VO by using the electronic configurations of the molecule instead of $\ce {V^2+}$.

Comment: Please check this paper with information on the electronic states of VO molecule: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4926393.

Comment: Since 19 months have gone by with no answers or votes, I think it's fair to let you know about [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) which also answers group theory questions, but make sure to delete the question from here if you're cross-posting there (or to at least put a note at the top of your question, saying that it's cross-posted).